# Construct DFA from context-free grammar

Tags: automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar, finite-automata

What is simplest and shortest way to build minimal DFA from context-free grammar (equivalent to regular grammar)? For example, the grammar:

```
A ::= aB
B ::= {b}
```

And the automaton:

```
      a           b
(0) ----> ((1)) <----
            |_______|
```

I know that there is one-step-algorithm to construct minimal DFA from regular expression, but I can not find similar for context-free grammar.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your grammar generates the language $\{ab\}$ and your automaton accepts the language $ab^*$ (if I interpret correctly your figure).

Comment: Sorry for the long absence. No, my grammar generates the language a{b}.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that $\{$ and $\}$ are part of the alphabet ??

Comment: No, just common EBNF. Look, parsing of string "abbb": `A ---1---> aB ---2---> abbb`. I mentioned that grammar is context-free but equivalent to regular.